# User preferences in Silverligth web application

Tags: silverlight

I need to create a user preferences dialog in a Silverlight web application in a way that a user can change settings (let's say background color in main window) and see the results after clicking on an "OK" button of the dialog without closing it.

I tried a child window and was not happy because the main window is blocked untill return from the child window, so the user cannot see the results immediately whild the window is open.

What would be a good way of implementing that?  Thanks for suggestions.
Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [FloatableWindow project on CodePlex](http://floatablewindow.codeplex.com/) created by [Tim Heuer](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2009/05/10/silverlight-childwindow-non-modal-refactor.aspx) which refactors the normal ChildWindow for non-modal use. You may be able to use it directly or create your own ChildWindow which does something similar.

It basically needs to re-enable to RootVisual which the normal ChildWindow disables by default, and get rid of the overlay which fades out the rest of your application.

Comment: thank you Dan,  the foatable widnow looks just rigth.  Cheers.